# Set Proxy authentication for ie using Vbscript

Tags: vbscript, vb6

I want to auto fill proxy authentication value of username and password for ie using vbscript.

After I added the proxy ip and port to Tools>Internet Option>Connection Tab>LAN Settings. I am prompted with the following dialog

[image: windows security dialog]

Is there anyways using VBS OR VB to auto fill this ?

So, far i have got the code like so

```
'begin script
Option Explicit
Dim valUserIn
Dim objShell, RegLocate
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
RegLocate = "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ProxyEnable"
objShell.RegWrite RegLocate,"0","REG_DWORD"
WScript.Sleep(1000)
valUserIn = Inputbox("Enter the Proxy server you want to use.","Proxy Server Required","proxygate.mydomain.com:8080")
if valUserIn = "" then
    RegLocate = "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ProxyEnable"
    objShell.RegWrite RegLocate,"0","REG_DWORD"
    'MsgBox "No proxy mode"
else
    RegLocate = "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ProxyServer"
    objShell.RegWrite RegLocate,valUserIn,"REG_SZ"
    RegLocate = "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ProxyEnable"
    objShell.RegWrite RegLocate,"1","REG_DWORD"
    'MsgBox "Proxy mode: " & valUserIn
end if
WScript.Quit
'end script
```

But this only set's the proxy ip and port.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can utilize the Sendkeys shell command which will type in and activate keyboard commands for you once it has allocated the correct screen. However, this is assuming you are running the script while it is open. If you are looking for something that prefills that data before hand. I'm afraid I cannot assist in that realm.

```
Dim WshShell, Success
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
'Wait for window to popup.... 
'if this doesn't activate it directly, try clicking on the window. 
Do Until Success = True
    Success = objShell.AppActivate("Windows Security")
    Wscript.Sleep 1000
Loop
WScript.Sleep 500 
WshShell.SendKeys "Username"
wscript.sleep 500 'allow program to have time to type it in. 
WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}" 'tab for password field
WshShell.SendKeys "Password"
wscript.sleep 500 'allow program to have time to type it in. 
WshShell.SendKeys "%o" 'Alt + O for hitting "OK" 
wscript.sleep 500
```